# Google Tag manager fires the tag but event is not shown in real time GA tab

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

[here's screen of tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J42jD.png)

Ga UA identifier is set properly.

I added all necessary codes to website: GA + GTM codes.

I don't know where the problem is. When I test if tag fires in GTM Preview everything works properly.

I'm so frustrated and really would appreciate any help.

Comment: I know you say it's set properly, but triple check your UA identifier. Verify that you're looking at GA UA and not GA4 in the GA interface. Do you have an request/adblocker running that might be preventing any data from leaving your computer and actually hitting GA? Assuming this is a low-volume website, do you see any data at all showing up in the GA profile (even if not in realtime)?

Comment: Yeah I checked it many times, yes it's GA UA identifier. I checked the analytics after couple of days and it's showing still 0 events, also 0 goals - cuz I tried to set GA UA goal also. What about some Wordpress plugin/s, can't it be the problem?

Comment: It may well be if you're using Wordpress. If you open your website and open the Developer Tools for your browser (e.g. Ctrl + Shift + J in  Chrome, then select the Network tab) and refresh the page, do you see an outbound request to Google Analytics (e.g. filter by "/collect")? If you don't see that, it's likely misconfigured in your admin panel, explaining why Google isn't showing anything at all.